# Stream Youtube videos via WD My Cloud (as Proxy) to ChromeCast or Apple TV

Tags: streaming, youtube, dlna, proxy, chromecast

Background: I stream a lot from Youtube through ChromeCast and Apple TV and and I'm trying to reduce Bandwidth.

I own a WD My Cloud 3 TB on the same network. Ideally, I want videos to be transparently cached on the WD My Cloud, if it is possible.

Such a transparent proxying isn't possible on the Google's Youtube app, I know. Are there any third party Youtube clients that have this option?

If there isn't such a solution, let's split the problem into two.

What is the simplest way (from an iPhone or an Android) to download youtube videos to my NAS - WD My Cloud.
What is the simplest way to stream from WD My Cloud into ChromeCast or Apple TV. I have found GPlayer on iPhone streams from the NAS to the Apple TV, but the stream happens through the phone. There's this LocalCast app on Android, that streams local videos on the device to both devices, but it doesn't connect to the My Cloud. The ideal app would stream directly from WD My Cloud to the Chromecast without going through the phone.

Comment: [`youtube-dl`](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) downloads videos from youtube.